# Regular Expression in BigQuery Match the First and Middle String

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am not good at using regular expression. Here's a sample value AC-00-OT-00
I need to check all of records if it's start with a word of AC and contains OT in the 2 dash

here's my sample scenario below:

```
AC-whatever number-OT-whatever number = TRUE
AC-whatever number-EF-whatever number = FALSE
OT-whatever number-AC-whatever number = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_CONTAINS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(val, r'^AC-\d{1,3}-OT-\d{1,3}$');
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. I tried to use this almost good but I noticed that it's capturing other values as long as it start with AC and the middle part is OT example: AC-00-00-AS-00-00-OT-00 = TRUE but it should return FALSE it should only follow this format AC-whatever number-OT-whatevernumber

Comment: Please post the real data.

Comment: This is real data. AC-00-00-AS-00-00-OT-00 this returned TRUE but it only should return TRUE on this format AC-00-OT-00

Comment: Sorry just to add the numbers may be in 1 digit or 2 digits or 3 digits.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: it works. thank you i will now mark your answer.